# $f > 0$ implies integral of $f$ is greater than $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a box, $f : Q \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable on $Q$. Claim: If $f(x) > 0 $ for all $x\in Q$, then $\displaystyle\int\limits_Q f > 0$.

Attempt:

Take any partition $P$ of $Q$ with subrectangles $Q_i$. Since $f >0 $ is given, then we have that $M_i (f) = \sup\limits_{x \in Q_i } f(x) > 0 $. Since $\operatorname{Vol}(Q_i) \geq 0 $, then we have

$$ M_i (f) \operatorname{Vol}(Q_i) > 0 \implies \sum U(P,f) = \sum M_i (f) \operatorname{Vol}(Q_i) > 0 $$

Taking inf over all partitions, we have:

$$ \int\limits_Qf  = \overline{ \int\limits_Q } f = \inf_{P} U(P,f) > 0 $$

as desired. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: No, the problems that you have here is that taking the infimum of a set of positive numbers can yield zero. For instance $\inf\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: It's difficult to know what you know. Here's a leading question: Must $f$ be continuous at some $a\in Q$?

Comment: I know continuity in a box $Q$ implies continuity. But, integrability may not imply continuity ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_k=\{x\in Q: f(x)\geq 1/k\}$. Then you have that $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3...$More over $\bigcup_k E_i=Q$ since $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. In particular there must be a first instance such that $E_k$ is not of empty volume.

Then, $\int_Q f\geq \int_{E_k} f\geq vol(E_k)\frac{1}{k}>0$.

Comment: What do you mean by first instance?

Comment: I dont understand this solution. Can you explain a little bit more please? In fact, I dont know what you mean when you say that there must be a first instance such thata $E_k$ is not empty. thanks