# question about integration and volume of a set

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a box and $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ . Put $E_k = \{ x \in Q : f(x) \geq \frac{1}{k} \} $ My question is: how does it follow that there exists at least one $E_i$ such that $Vol(E_i) > 0 $ ??

Added: $f > 0$

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $f$?

Comment: a condition is added

Comment: How do you define $Vol$? or do you just mean one of the $E_i$ does not have measure zero?

Comment: volume zero....

Comment: Is $f$ integrable by any chance?

Comment: My answer relies on $f$ being integrable, if you are sure this is not the case tell me.

Comment: not integrable.

Comment: Anyways I just noticed my answer does not need integrability since $f=0$ almost everywhere gives $f$ integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the $E_i$ have content(volume) zero then their union over all $n \in \Bbb N$ has measure zero, that is $\{x:f(x) \neq 0\}$ has measure zero. This would imply that $\int_{Q} f=0$* but we know $f>0$ which implies $\int_{Q} f >0$(If it exists, if it doesn't we have already reached a contradiction by showing $f$ is integrable) thus we have a contradiction.

*If $f\neq 0$ on a set of measure zero, call it $A$ then $\int_{Q} f=\int_{A^c} f+\int_{A}f=\int_{A^c}0+\int_{A}f=0$ since the integral of a function on a set of measure zero is always zero.

To see why $\int_{Q} f >0$: Since $f>0$ (and continuous) there is some neighbourhood $B\subseteq Q$ of which $f\ge a>0$ , then $\int_{B} f \ge \int_{B} a=aVol(B)>0$. Note that this needs continuity at one point, which we have since $f$ is taken to be integrable and thus its set of discontinuities has measure zero.

Comment: I dont sew why $f > 0 $ implies $\int_Q f > 0$. Can you show this ?

Comment: @user139708 Didn't you ask this question yesterday?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742209/f-0-implies-integral-of-f-is-greater-than-0?rq=1

Comment: @user139708 Oh now I see, you need this to answer your previous question right?

Comment: @user139708 I will add that to the answer in a minute.

Comment: @user139708 I have added it.

Comment: I see but I dont understand why $ f \geq a > 0 $ ?

Comment: By continuity if $f\ge a$ at a point then it greater than it in a nbhd, try proving it.

Comment: You can do it for $a=0$ then take the function $f-a$ for a non-zero $a$